# Is it possible to programmatically fire up a free AWS VPS complete with a Github project in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I was working on a project that needed a Database, and while I normally use MySQL, I decided to try MongoDB because I thought the schema/index model would be a better fit for what I was trying to do. Since then, I've used MongoDB in almost all of my Node.js programs. One thing that I found interesting about MongoDB itself was the hosting of it. I noticed that it was free, something that most commercial databases are not, and was intrigued.

After some research, I found out that when you create a DB, Mongo fires up a free AWS VPS.

I was wondering: Is this possible to replicate in Node.js? I would like to set up a VPS on AWS (free tier), connect a github node.js project, and run the Node.js project all from a remote project.

Could this be done?

Thanks :)